# String/Array checking php

Tags: php, arrays, find, offset

How can I check if the first 2 characters of an array are 0x?
here is an example:

```
$hex = "0xFFFF";
if($hex[0:2].find('0x')==0)
{
print("0x Found.");
}
else
{
print("0x Not Found.");
}
```

Can anyone create an alternative that works?

Comment: How about switch statements

Comment: Are you really talking about an array? $hex in your example is a string.

Comment: The first two characters of an array or string?  In PHP these are different things (thought they do have the concept of array access for strings)

Comment: `$hex[0:2]` - PHP does not have nice stuff like that. Consider using Python if you like having a nice operator to get a slice from a string.

Comment: I was just using a string as an example but the solution is pretty much the same for an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hex = '0xFFFF';
if ($hex[0].$hex[1] == '0x')
{
    print("0x Found.");
}
else
{
    print("0x Not Found.");
}
```

Without needing to use any function. See this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-80) for it's usage.

Answer (score 1):

If `$hex` is a string this is rather easy

```
if (strpos($hex, '0x') === 0) {
    print("0x Found.");
} else {
    print("0x Not Found.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strnicmp` ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)) looks good.

```
$hex = '0xFFFF';
if (strnicmp($hex, '0x', 2) == 0)
{
    print("0x Found.");
}
else
{
    print("0x Not Found.");
}
```

Looks for an insensitive '0x' string at the beginning of your `$hex` var.

Answer (score 0):

You can [access string characters as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-80) to get the first and second index and check if they are 0 and x.

```
<?php
$hex = array("0xFFF","5xFFF","0xDDD");
$len = count($hex);
$msg = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if ($hex[$i][0] == "0" && $hex[$i][1] == "x") {
        $msg .= $hex[$i] . ' starts with 0x!' . "\n";
    }
}
echo ($msg);
?>
```